# Как правильно обработать не существующий товар во vue js, c использование роутов

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Есть проект, в котором используется Vuex, VueRoute, Vue-Resource

Существуют товары, которые открываются по пути 'product/id'
Есть файл роутов, который описывает отдельно роуты и привязку к компонентам.
В конце самом добавлен такой роут:

```
path: '/*',
name: 'Error',
component: Error
```

Но он не обрабатывает если ID в списке продуктов не существует.
К примеру у меня 10 товаров, я ввожу путь 'product/15' в итоге получаю просто страницу с пустым компонентом. Как правильно обрабатывать текущую ситуацию?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте хук `router.beforeEach(from,to,next)`. Там можно проверить условие и в случае ошибки сделать редирект. Это называется navigation guards

Comment: Правильно, так и делал, но как загрузить стор чтобы проверить ID, перед хуком. У меня срабатывает проверка раньше чем загрузился стор, стор гружу в App.vue в блоке created

Comment: Видимо стор грузится с сервера, для этого нужно время. Поэтому я бы использовал флаг ожидания загрузки либо подгружал список доступных id, но в любом случае нужен промежуточный шаг с лоадером

Comment: а как этот флаг сделать? Я так понимаю в сторе нужно его реализовывать?

Comment: Я делаю так: `store.state.loading: 0`, далее на каждый запрос данных через `dispatch`  устанавливать флаг в += 1,а после выполнения - =1. Потребуется мутация `setLoading(state, val) { state.loading += val} `. Тогда запись +=1 будет выглядеть так `ctx.commit('setLoading', 1)`